# Check if convex polytope contained inside a union of convex polytopes?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, polytopes

Suppose I have a polytope $\mathcal P$ and a set of other polytopes $\{\mathcal S_0,\dots,\mathcal S_N\}$. Is there a computationally efficient way to check that $\mathcal P\subseteq\bigcup_{i=0}^{N}\mathcal S_i$? You can assume that both halfspace and vertex representations are available.

Comment: Does convex hull of the union ==  convex hull of the (union + polytope)?  

If the union part has gaps, then things are trickier.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that the union may have gaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Baotic, M., "Polytopic Computations in Constrained Optimal Control"](https://hrcak.srce.hr/index.php?id_clanak_jezik=71840&show=clanak) describes the `polycover` algorithm which does just this. The computational complexity has an exponential flavor, but in practice the algorithm performs pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is difficult. Even the convex hull
of the union of two polytopes
is of recent (2017) interest.

> Conforti, Michele, Marco Di Summa, and Yuri Faenza. "Balas formulation for the union of polytopes is optimal." arXiv preprint [arXiv:1711.00891](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00891) (2017).